# Should Precision-Recall Area Under the Curve be similar when running binary classification and isolating a OnevsRest class AUC?

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning, precision-recall, auc

I am currently using `sklearn` [OnevsRest](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html) classifier on a dataset. The observations of my datasets are describing actual mammals and the columns of the datasets are some mammals features.

All mammals that are not felines are in class `0`. Different kind of felines are in classes from `1` to `4`. When I compute the Precision-Recall Area under the curve (PR AUC) for the class `0` I get an AUC close to `1`.

However, when I run the binary detection on my dataset with all mammals that are not felines are in class `0`, and all kinds of feline are in class `1`, I get a PR AUC close to 0 (with either `y_score = clf.predict_proba(Xtest)[:,0]` or `y_score = clf.predict_proba(Xtest)[:,1]`).

Should both PR AUC I am referring to be similar? I am not giving a code example because I am only looking for a clarification regarding the theory.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.